# Resetting timer in Matlab GUI after button push

Tags: matlab

So I made a GUI using AppDesigner where it look like:

[image]

And the two white boxes are actual the UITextArea elements of the App Designer. Above is when the app has executed, the timer starts counting down and showing the time on the UITextArea. The code i used for the timer is as below:

```
methods (Access = private)

    function countdown(app)
        while true
            try
                minute = 29;
                set(app.TextArea1, 'Value', num2str(minute));
                seconds = 0;
                set(app.TextArea2, 'Value', num2str(seconds));
                while minute > 0
                    seconds = 59;
                    while seconds > 0
                        set(app.TextArea2, 'Value', num2str(seconds));
                        pause(1);
                        seconds = seconds - 1;
                    end
                    minute = minute - 1;
                    set(app.TextArea1, 'Value', num2str(minute));
                end
            catch
                break;
            end
        end
    end
```

And since i want the timer to start ticking at startup, i called the function at startup:

```
function startupFcn(app)    
        app.countdown;
end
```

However, the problem I'm having now is that i have this button, upon pushing it, i would want the timer to reset back to it's original value and start ticking down again.

```
function ResetButtonPushed(app, event)
    app.countdown
    %other process executes here onwards.
    .
    .
end
```

But the problem is that, i want other process which comes after calling app.countdown to continue, where in my case, the program waits for app.countdown to finish executing before moving to the next line. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property `ResetFlag = 0`. In your `countdown` method, you have to add a `if` condition and run your proccess one time.

```
properties (Access = private)
   ResetFlag = 0
end

function countdown(app)
   while true
   try
   if app.ResetFlag
      disp('My Proccess');
      app.ResetFlag = 0;
   end
...
```

Set the flag to 1 in the ResetButton callback function.

```
function ResetButtonPushed(app, event)
   app.ResetFlag = 1;
   app.countdown();
end
```